# Show dev.azure.com projects in portal.azure.com projects

Tags: azure-devops, azureportal

We're in the middle of evaluating Azure and have hit an issue where we can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Our team have created several projects under the dev.azure.com webpage, all working perfectly and far better than we had hoped for.

However we don't seem to be able to connect these individual projects to the "DevOps Projects" page on the portal.azure.com projects page.

Any projects we create on portal.azure.com are shown on the projects on dev.azure.com but not the other way round.

If we go to the Resources page on portal.azure.com We can see all "Organisations" created on dev.azure.com so there's certainly a connection, but that's it.

Does anyone know how to successfully bring in all the projects from the dev.azure.com to be shown and thus centrally managed on the portal.azure.com webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to successfully bring in all the projects from the dev.azure.com to be shown and thus centrally managed on the portal.azure.com webpage?

I am afraid we could not bring all the project from dev.azure.com to be shown on the portal.azure.com webpage.

This behavior is **by designed**, you can get the feedback from following thread:

[DevOps Project not appearing in "Azure DevOps Project" blade](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/409516/devops-project-not-appearing-in-azure-devops-proje.html)

> In this case, if you create the project in the Azure DevOps
>   portal(dev.azure.com) you will not see the project in Azure Portal
>   DevOps Projects blade. If you create a project in Azure portal DevOps
>   Projects blade(portal.azure.com), you can see the project in Azure
>   DevOps portal.

If it is important to you, you can submit your request for this feature on the [suggest a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and wow, I can't believe this isn't part of the integration!